# After MS Access Conversion 97 --> 2002 I get 'Enter Parameter Value' when exitting a form

Tags: ms-access, parameters

So when I exit a form from my newly converted .mdb it asks to Enter Parameter Value.

It goes through (ie if i enter a value, it asks for another) the values required for a query that is run on a List Box on the page.  The query has not been changed during the conversion.

The values it is getting for the query are from text boxes on the same form.

There are a few Requeries in the form (run from VB) so I imagine that it is rerunning again on Exit (although this isnt explicit in the form properties).

I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this.

Your help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article : [BUG: Enter Parameter Value Dialog Box Appears While Trying to Close a Form Window](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=811860)

Comment: Looks like another reason to get away from A2002 and use something more recent...